# The role of gas pressure in the life cycle of stars

Tags: pressure, astrophysics, astronomy, stars, gas

As a high school student, I am curious about the significance of gas pressure in the life cycle of a star. While I have read about the radiation pressure and the pressure caused by the energy released in fusion processes, I am wondering how "gas pressure" plays a role. Is it significant enough to be considered, and how does it affect the volume of the different stages of a star?

**Furthermore, how does gas pressure change during the various phases of a star's life cycle?**

Comment: See Graur's book *Supernova* for an excellent explanation.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "gas pressure". Hydrostatic pressure? Of course it is significant. Is the pressure of a stellar atmosphere (everything above the photosphere) significant? Probably not all that much, at least not for the interior of the star.

Comment: Yes, hydrostatic pressure